# TF 2.0: Where can I find the upgrade of tf.contrib.training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use the HParams class from **tf.contrib.training** in tensorflow 2.0 version, but I can't find the replacement for this class neither in *tensorflow alpha* documentation nor in *tensorflow_addons*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reviewing some guides and the new `hparams` API, I have concluded that there is no such class. However, in the new API there exists an `HParam` class, and the equivalent of an `HParams` object is just a list of `HParam` objects.

Check the [hparams API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/hparams/api.py) for more details. You can also learn how to use the new API in this guide: [Hyperparameter Tuning with the HParams Dashboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams)